# Difference between < and << for using readarray

Tags: bash

I was filling my array with values that were present in a file. I used  < and it worked perfectly fine but when I used << it didn't work.

According to my knowledge, < and << are used for redirection. < will override the contents of a file whereas, << will append the new contents to the file.

Perfectly working code

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a array
array[0]="hi"
readarray array < file

echo ${array[@]}
```

Non-working code

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a array
array[0]="hi"
readarray array << file

echo ${array[@]}
```

Answer (score 5):

You are mistaken. `>` overwrites a file, while `>>` appends to it.  `<` reads input from a file, but `<<` indicates the start of a heredoc.  When you write:

```
cmd << file
some text
file
```

`cmd` takes the lines between `<< file` and the line containing only the string `file` as its stdin.  The common usage is to embed input to the command directly in the script, and a more descriptive delimiter than "file" is usually chosen.  A common choice is the string EOF.  eg:

```
cat > file << EOF
this will be written to file
EOF
```

is a common idiom for writing specific content to a file.

Comment: There is also a third construct <<< which takes input from a literal (or variable). For example:

INP="hello there";    tr a-z A-Z <<< $INP

Produces "HELLO THERE"